# Write VBA that sets each element in 2nd column of an array, to a new nested array of size n, where n is an integer from the 1st column

Tags: arrays, vba, nested

For any 2-column array A, set every 2nd-column element to be a 1-dimensional array with a size indicated by the first column.

For example: the row [3,""] would become [3,("","","")]

Something like this?

```
Option Base 1

Sub NestArrays()
    Dim OuterArray(3,2) as variant   'create OuterArray with hypothetical numbers 3,5,7
    OuterArray(1,1) = 3  
    OuterArray(2,1) = 5
    OuterArray(3,1) = 7

    for i = 1 to Ubound(OuterArray)       ' for every row in OuterArray
        size = OuterArray(i,1)            ' set variable "size" equal to the element in 1st column
        OuterArray(i,2)=Array(1 to size)  ' <--- this doesn't work, set 2nd-col element = array(size)
    next i

   ''''test
   OuterArray(1,2)(1) = "aardvark"
   debug.print OuterArray(1,2)(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: So given the example the output array should look like [3, ("", "", "")], [5, ("", "", "", "", "")], [7, ("", "", "", "", "", "", "")] ?

Answer (score 2):

Use an intermediate array and `ReDim` as `size` is dynamic. You possibly want a safeguard on `size` as well as it needs to be >0 (just a thought)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub NestArrays()
    Dim outerArray(3, 2) As Variant, i As Long, size As Long 'create OuterArray with hypothetical numbers 3,5,7
    
    outerArray(1, 1) = 3
    outerArray(2, 1) = 5
    outerArray(3, 1) = 7
    
    Dim arr()
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(outerArray)              ' for every row in OuterArray
        size = outerArray(i, 1)                  ' set variable "size" equal to the element in 1st column
        ReDim arr(1 To size)
        outerArray(i, 2) = arr
    Next i

    ''''test
    outerArray(1, 2)(1) = "aardvark"
    Debug.Print outerArray(1, 2)(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The host array is declared to hold items of type variant.  As you can assign an array to a Variant you can proceed as follows

```
Dim myIndex as long
For  Lbound(OuterArray,1) to Ubound(OuterArray,1)

     OuterArray(myIndex,2) = Split(String$(OuterArray(myIndex,1),","),",")

Next
```

If you need the new array to be also an array of variants you will need to create a function that generates the appropriate size of array.

```
Public Function VarArray(ByVal ipCount As Long) As Variant

    Dim mySd As Object
    Set mySd = CreateObject("Scripting.DIctionary")
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = 1 To ipCount
    
        mySd.Add myIndex, 0
    
    Next
    
    VarArray = mySd.Items
    
End Function
```

So that

```
OuterArray(myIndex,2) = Split(String$(OuterArray(myIndex,1),","),",")
```

becomes

```
OuterArray(myIndex,2) =VarArray(OuterArray(myIndex,1))
```